# MySQL query returns too many results with double join

Tags: mysql

Ok I'm trying to return these 4 values for any entry in simacc_payments that has a verified value of 0.

```
    SELECT themes.value, members.real_name, simacc_payments.pay_amt, simacc_payments.pay_date
    FROM simacc_payments
    INNER JOIN members
    ON simacc_payments.id_member = members.id_member
    INNER JOIN themes
    ON simacc_payments.id_member = themes.id_member
    WHERE verified = "0"
    ORDER BY members.real_name ASC, simacc_payments.pay_date DESC
```

The array I'm getting out as my result comes out like this, simplied

```
    real_name, id_member, pay_amt, pay_date
    real_name, value, pay_amt, pay_date
    real_name, id_member, payments.pay_amt, payments.pay_date
    real_name, value, pay_amt, pay_date
```

So every second entry in the array is correct, I know this has something to do with the join but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.  Please someone give me the answer while I still have some hair left :)

Comment: Could you provide your schema so we can check the statement more accurate?

Comment: Thanks heaps bish... your request gave my brain the kick in the arse it needed...  The problem was because of a completely unrelated value in the themes table... now all I need to do is try to find a way to filter them out.

Comment: So the problem you describe in your question solved?

Comment: not actually solved but I know where the problem is coming from now, so now I need to try and figure out how to limit the results to remove the error.  I could split the query into 2 but the forum framework I'm working within says you should use joins rather than separate queries and I'm not sure if there is a reason for that within the framework itself.

Comment: Maybe you can work with `limit` or subqueries. Can't give you more help without infos. But good luck resolving your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just for anyone who ends up here with similar problems.  My issues was cause by a second value in my Themes table for each use.  Essentially I had to add an extra condition to my WHERE clause to filter these out.  Hope that helps someone.

Comment: If you provide the updated query with your explanation it will be helpful forever.